# How to use variable in openoffice basic's formular?

Tags: formula, openoffice-basic

`rule` is a worksheet's name,the command works fine:

```
oCell.Formula = "=LOOKUP(A2;$'rule'.$A$2:$A$9;$'rule'.$B$2:$B$9)"
```

I want to make the first A2 in LOOKUP with a variable:

```
for id=2 to NumRows
     oCell = Sheet.getCellrangeByName("B"&id)
     arg = "A"&id
     oCell.Formula = "=LOOKUP(arg;$'rule'.$A$2:$A$9;$'rule'.$B$2:$B$9)" 
 next id
```

The arg will not assign its value into LOOKUP ,how to fix it?

[oCell.Formula = "=LOOKUP(arg;$'rule'.$A$2:$A$9;$'rule'.$B$2:$B$9)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgla9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use quoting syntax similar to the line where you defined `arg`.

```vb
id = 2
MsgBox("=LOOKUP(A" & id & ";$'rule'.$A$2:$A$9;$'rule'.$B$2:$B$9)")
```

Result:

```
=LOOKUP(A2;$'rule'.$A$2:$A$9;$'rule'.$B$2:$B$9)
```